# Update RequestLocalizationOptions while application is running and a new culture is added in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, localization, culture

How can I update RequestLocalizationOptions while application is running and a new culture is added avoiding to restart the application?

Hello! I have an application that supports localizations. All the resources and values are stored in the database. I will show you how I configured the RequestLocalizationOptions.

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddRequestLocalizationOptions(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(async options =>
            {
                using var scope = services?.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope();
                var cultureService = scope!.ServiceProvider!.GetService<ICultureService>();
                if (cultureService is not null)
                {
                    var cultures = await cultureService.GetFromDatabase(x => x.Available == true);

                    IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>();
                    foreach (var culture in cultures)
                    {
                        supportedCultures.Add(new CultureInfo($"{culture.language}-{culture.CountryCodeIso2}")); // en-US, it-IT and so on
                    }

                    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
                    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                    options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
                {
                    new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
                };

                    var cookieRequestCultureProvider = options.RequestCultureProviders.OfType<CookieRequestCultureProvider>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (cookieRequestCultureProvider is not null)
                        cookieRequestCultureProvider.CookieName = CookieDefaults.CultureKey;
                }
            });

            return services;
        }
```

The final configuration step is to enable the localization middleware using the **UseRequestLocalization** method.

```cs
app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

The **UseRequestLocalization** method initializes the **RequestLocalizationOptions** object we configured above. **UseRequestLocalization** enables localization and internationalization by setting the culture and UI culture for each user request based on their language preferences.

Everything work fine except one case. Let's say I have 3 cultures available in the database this means that options.SupportedCultures it will contains all 3 cultures. But if I will update the database and I will add another 3 available cultures while application is running, how can I update the RequestLocalizationOptions to specify that now I support 6 cultures without restarting the application? Because the AddRequestLocalizationOptions extension it will be executed on the startup only one time, but I need somehow to refresh the options while the application is running. If I restart the application, it works as expected but I don't want to restart the application when it will be on production every time I'm adding a new culture..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that first you change the way how you are Configuring `RequestLocalizationOptions` as following:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>(provider =>
{
    return new ConfigureNamedOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>(Options.DefaultName, options =>
    {
        using var scope = provider.CreateScope();
        var cultureService = scope!.ServiceProvider!.GetService<ICultureService>();
        if (cultureService is not null)
        {
            var cultures = cultureService.GetFromDatabase(x => x.Available == true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>();
            foreach (var culture in cultures)
            {
                supportedCultures.Add(new CultureInfo($"{culture.language}-{culture.CountryCodeIso2}")); // en-US, it-IT and so on
            }

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
            {
                new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
            };

            var cookieRequestCultureProvider = options.RequestCultureProviders.OfType<CookieRequestCultureProvider>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (cookieRequestCultureProvider is not null)
                cookieRequestCultureProvider.CookieName = CookieDefaults.CultureKey;
        }
    });
});
```

for two reasons:

1. Building the service provider your self from the service collection, might cause singleton services to be resolved twice.
2. Using async is the same as using async on void methods which is a bad practice.

After you do that change, use `IOptionsSnapshot<RequestLocalizationOptions>` on your middleware.`

At this point it would be more straight forward to write the code that fetches the options from database into the middleware it self. So you will avoid the blocking call to `GetFromDatabase` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I will implement a middleware to validate the culture route parameter. But to avoid calling the database every time to check if the application support the culture from route, I will use memory cache for this. First I will check the cultures in memory cache. If nothing is there, I will get them from database and then I will store the cultures in memory cache with a small expiration time. In this way, I will interact more with the memory cache. Also, if a new culture is added in the database, I will update the memory cache with the new fresh data from database.

Comment: But if I implement a middleware, I don't think it's needed anymore to configure the RequestLocalizationOptions, because the culture verification will be made in the middleware. The good part with RequestLocalizationOptions configuration and app.UseRequestLocalization(); is that the culture is automatically verified if it's valid and supported by the app and if not, the default culture is returned..

Comment: If you move the logic of reading cultures to the middleware you will not have the need to configure RequestLocalizationOptions on startup anymore that's true, also doing a in-memory cache is a good idea.

Comment: So instead of trying somehow to update the SupportedCultures from RequestLocalizationOptions while applications is running to avoid restarting the application, I will use memory cache to store there the supportedCultures and a custom middleware to verify the culture from request..

Comment: in my opinion that will be the easiest solution to this, there might be better approaches...